# Is there a way to force Reagan to stay in Beirut after 1983 bombing?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, cold-war

Is there any possibility for Reagan to stay entangled in the Lebanese civil war after the suicide attack on the barracks in 1983?

Maybe a missile attack that sinks one of the carriers would force Reagan's hand and would be hard to deny by Iran & Syria.

I don't know how plausible is to have larger intervention since its still the cold war, and Vietnam  was still a fresh wound. At minimum staying on the original mission would do for my world.

> The mission of the multinational force was to ensure the withdrawal of
>   all foreign forces; aid, support and train the Lebanese Armed Forces
>   to restore the sovereignty of the Lebanese Government

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_Force_in_Lebanon
http://foreignpolicy.com/2014/02/07/when-reagan-cut-and-run/

Comment: Hell *H.G.Rael* and welcome to Worldbuilding.  Unfortunately, this question seems rather opinion based.  Questions on this site are expected to have a clear way of judging answers.  At this point it seems there are a near-infinite number of plausible answers.  Please visit our [help] and take the [tour] for more information about the site.

Comment: This seems like a test of you as a storyteller. We're not going to make your story for you. Happily, politics can be as benign or chaotic as you, the storyteller, make it. However, one basic tenet of multinational peacekeeping forces is that they are honest brokers for trust-building among former foes who have honestly agreed to end fighting. They are generally not an invasion, judgement, or punishment force.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he could be forced to keep forces there. Compare 1941, 1983, and 9/11. In one case the US left, in two cases they became so angry that they fought.

- Does the US leadership believe that there is a vital national interest at stake? Perhaps the Soviet Union offered to send a couple of divisions, plus air force and navy bases, and to *stay as long as it takes.* The West might not pull out then.
- Or the US believes that leaving would seriously endanger the existence of Israel.

If you are writing an *alternate history*, get clear about the point of departure even if it is never spelled out in the book. Perhaps the White House gets an intelligence report that the Communists are going to exploit the pullback.